# What is the difference between using a pointer symbol inside the angle brackets of a vector vs using them outside

Tags: c++

This isn't very much of an issue I am having but more just me just wanting to understand something.

What is the is the difference between using a * like this

```cpp
vector<Emp*> empList;
```

vs using it like this

```cpp
vector<Emp>* empList;
```

In a project I was working on, it give me an error when I tried to do this

```cpp
vector<Emp>* empList;
empList->push_back(new empChild("Kyle"));
```

but when I changed it, it worked

```cpp
vector<Emp*> empList;
empList.push_back(new EmpChild("Kyle"));
```

I don't understand why.

Emp is a parent class
EmpChild is a derived class of Emp

Comment: Do you want to point to a vector or do you want a vector that contains pointers?

Comment: Looks like there are some holes in your knowledge of pointers and templates. 
 Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to fill them.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> vector<Emp*> empList;
> ```

is a vector containing pointers to `Emp` (which is what you want when using inheritance).

> ```
> vector<Emp>* empList;
> ```

is a pointer to a vector that contains `Emp` (causes object slicing, you don't want that in inheritance).

**Edit**

As pointed out in the comments, you probably should consider using `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers. The advantage of those is that they manage the object for you (meaning they will delete it for you, which avoids potential memory leaks). So you should use

```
vector<unique_ptr<Emp>> empList;
```

instead of

> ```
> vector<Emp*> empList;
> ```

However, you now have to use `vector::emplace_back` instead of `vector::push_back`:

```
empList.emplace_back(new EmpChild("Kyle"));
```

(That's related to how `std::unique_ptr` works)

Comment: And then there's `vector<Emp**>***`.

Comment: I am afraid the OP is lost, may be say explicitly  to consider `vector<unique_ptr<Emp>> empList;` in place of `vector<Emp*> empList;` (there are two cases in the answer) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here with

```
vector<Emp*> empList;
```

empList is an object of type vector that store Emp pointers, the instance is created on the stack and implicitly instantiate and allocate for you. whereas with

```
vector<Emp>* empList;
```

you're declaring empList as a pointer of vector type.  You could get the second one to work but you need to allocate and instantiate it explicitly, i.e you need to call

```
vector<Emp>* empList = new vector<Emp>(); <--- something like this to instantiate
empList->push_back(...);
....
....
// need to clean up after not longer use
delete empList;
```

Comment: _the instance is created on the stack_ really ? you do not know where the line _vector<Emp*> empList;_ comes from, can be the declaration of an attribute in a class  (whose instances can be allocated in the heap), or a global variable ;-)

Answer (score 0):

That `*` is part of the **name** of a **type**. Always look at the type that the `*` applies too. `Emp*` means "pointer-to-Emp", so `vector<Emp*>` means "vector of pointer-to-Emp", that is, a vector that holds pointers. `vector<Emp>*` means "pointer to vector-of-Emp", so its a pointer to a vector that holds objects of type `Emp`.

As for the error message, when you have an object you use `.` to access its members; when you have a pointer to an object you use `->` to access the members of the object that it points at.